# How to replace and edit characters in a string?

Tags: c

So here's my code:

```
main()
{
        char input[150];                                                                        //Create a variable of type char named input to store user input

        printf(" Enter a standard line: ");                                                     //Ask the user for some standard input

        if (fgets(input, 150, stdin) == NULL)                                                   //Initiate a series of checks to make sure there is valid input
        {
                puts(" End-of-File or Input Error Detected. ");                                 //If the end of the file is reached or there is a problem with input output a message
        }
        else if (input[0] == '\n')                                                              //If the user neglected to enter anything output a message
        {
                puts(" Oops! Looks like you forgot to enter something! ");
        }
        else
        {
                printf(" Here's what you entered: %s ", input);                                 //If there is valid user input echo it back to the user

                while (input[0] != '\n')
                {

                       (can I put the while loop here?)
                }
        }
}
```

I just got my code to run (courtesy of Chux here on Stackoverflow) and now I have another problem. Now that I can validate there is input, I have to replace and adjust the input line accordingly by replacing certain characters with their ASCII code, changing alphabet letter cases, and wrapping the line.

For example:
1. user inputs: google.COM/search?client
2. program changes and prints back to the user as: GOOGLE.com%2FSEARCH%3FCLIENT

HOW do I do that? Can I just leave the while loop where it is?

Comment: be more specific to your question please.

Comment: @kishanoza I thought I was pretty specific. Or did you mean that I should put in an example of what it's supposed to do?

Comment: exactly please put the example

Comment: @kishanoza Okay. I put an example up.

Comment: `while (input[0] != '\n')` always test the same thing.  Code likely needs an indexed access to `input[]`.  Something like `for (i=0; input[i] != '\0'; i++) {...`

Comment: **int i = 0; while(input[i] != "\n"){.... //some code i++;}** try this

Comment: Just setup a loop, change lower case characters to upper and vise versa.  stop when `'\0';` is reached.  As posted, this is too broad.  Show what you have tried concerning changing the characters' case.

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't use this----> while(input[0] != '\n');

let's say your input[0] is equal to \n this loop continues forever so maybe try to do it like input[i] != '\n' and increase the i in the loop